# c# system.net.dns universal app (W10) not working

Tags: c#, dns, win-universal-app

I tried to get IP adress from DNS by using
`IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com");` in univesal c# windows app.

But it shows me error
`Error   CS0103  The name 'Dns' does not exist in the current context`

I tried it in console app, it works perfectly. Namespace System.Net doesnt contain Dns in win 10 universal app. Could you tell me, where is problem or another solution?

My CODE

```
using System.Net;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string zaznam = In.Text;
    IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: To get it work for me, I had to remove the www, so just ("google.com") .. Sorry, didn't read the bit that you were trying to get it work in windows app,

Comment: in windows universal app? It works for me in cosole app but not in universal :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is correct. System.Net.Dns is not available in the [.Net Framework for Windows Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You can use the Windows Runtime classes instead: Call Windows.Networking.Sockets.[DatagramSocket.GetEndpointPairsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.getendpointpairsasync.aspx) then examine the returned  [EndpointPairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.endpointpair.aspx)

```
async Task ListEndpoints()
{
    HostName host = new HostName("www.stackoverflow.com");
    var eps = await DatagramSocket.GetEndpointPairsAsync(host, "80");
    foreach(EndpointPair ep in eps)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("EP {0} {1}",new object[] { ep.LocalHostName, ep.RemoteHostName });
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks cool, but i cant really understand, why this code gives me this error: 
`Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.` I never used method like this.

Comment: Exactly what the error says: you need to mark the containing method as async. This is an important and necessary pattern to understand when writing Universal apps in C#. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx for an overview

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you do the following instead ConsoleApp

```
IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com");
```

or if there are more Ip addresses you can do the following

```
IPAddress[] ips;
ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com");
Console.WriteLine("GetHostAddresses({0}) returns:", "google.com");//if you are passing in a hostname inside a method change this to hostname variable
foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
{
    Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
}
```

> Universal APP try the following below Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation namespace

```
public void DnsLookup(string hostname)
{
    var endpoint = new DnsEndPoint(hostname, 0);
    DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync(endpoint, OnNameResolved, null);  
}

private void OnNameResolved(NameResolutionResult result)
{
    IPEndPoint[] endpoints = result.IPEndPoints;
    // Do something with your endpoints
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it isnt working, Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation namespace is for WP, not universal app :/ I want to run it under W10(M) Sorry, I wrongly formule the question, I will edit it to be more obvious.