# How to create a System.Net.Sockets.Socket instance for Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-phone-8

this may be a stupid question since I am completely new to Windows Phone development - I've got some experience with developing in C# though... Anyways, I cannot figure out what is going on and MSDN is confusing me, maybe I got it all wrong.

I am simply trying to send UDP datagrams from a Lumia 925 to my PC, so I created an empty Windows Phone 8.1 app via VS wizard (MSVS 2015). Now, MSDN says there's supposed to be a [socket class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.105).aspx) for Windows Phone 8.1, but there isn't even a Sockets namespace in `System.Net`. Now I tried my luck with [DatagramSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.aspx)s, which, according to MSDN, should feature a method [GetEndpointPairsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701245.aspx), but it doesn't.

I thought maybe I'm missing assemblies I'd have to add to the References, but in the Add References dialog, there is hardly anything to be found. I'm starting to think that I missed out something very fundamental.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need use `Windows.Networking.Sockets` instead of `System.Net.Sockets`. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477961/cannot-find-system-net-sockets-assembly-for-wp-8-1))

As for `GetEndpointPairsAsync()` you may try this:

> ```
>     async Task ListEndpoints()
>     {
>         HostName host = new HostName("www.stackoverflow.com");
>         var eps = await DatagramSocket.GetEndpointPairsAsync(host, "80");
>         foreach (EndpointPair ep in eps)
>         {
>             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EP {0} {1}", new object[] { ep.LocalHostName, ep.RemoteHostName });
>         }
>     }
> ```

More information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754406/c-sharp-system-net-dns-universal-app-w10-not-working/34756693).

Comment: So is this a mistake in MSDN? After all, it clearly says "Namespace: System.Net.Sockets" as well as "Version Information: Windows Phone OS; Supported in: 8.1, 8.0, 7.1; Platforms: Windows Phone".

Comment: @iko79 Note its organization structure of the document. [Windows Phone Silverlight development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402535(v=vs.105).aspx)->Windows Phone API reference->.NET API for Windows Phone->System.Net.Sockets->Socket Class. So socket class in your question is for Windows Phone Silverlight. But you created a Windows Runtime project by selecting "Blank App" listed first. You may need select "Blank App(Windows Phone Silverlight)".